# Pricing api for the Aws Savings plan?

Tags: aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm currently working on developing an AWS cost calculator. I've managed to retrieve the reserved and on-demand prices using the query API successfully.

However, I've encountered an issue as the API doesn't provide pricing information for savings plans. Is there a separate API available for fetching savings plan prices, or is there an alternative method to obtain this information? I'm building this application using the Nest.js framework. Any guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Any method or way by which i can get the perunite pricing for perticular instance